# Is there a way to exclude certain source files or folders from a makefile?

Tags: build, makefile

Is there a way to exclude some files from the compilation process? Or even whole directories?

I believe the makefile is using `find` to find all the source files inside the `src` directory. Is there a way to specify the directories to ignore from `find`? Like some switch, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends entirely how your makefile is written. You can use conditionals to avoid adding files given certain conditions hold:

```
 ifeq ($(OS),win32)
 SOURCES += foo_win32.cpp
 else
 SOURCES += foo_posix.cpp
 endif
 ...
 foo: $(SOURCES)
```

If you elaborated a little on exactly you want to do, you may get a better answer.

EDIT: If the files are determined by running find, you can exclude files/directories from find like this:

```
SOURCES:=$(shell find srcdir -type f | grep -v dirtoexclude)
```

Comment: The find command has syntax for excluding files, but it is rather convoluted. I usually pass the find output through grep in these cases: "find ... | grep -v somedir".

Comment: BTW: using find to determine which source files to compile is bad practise, since any file which happens to reside in your source tree will be included. You should consider a static list instead.

Comment: Just adding my 2cents on a monster old question, you could `shell find srcdir -name "*.c"` for example to avoid bloating your sources list.

Answer (score 2):

Makepp (a replacement for Make) can do this:

http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_cookbook.html#Matching%20all%20files%20except%20a%20certain%20subset

Answer (score -1):

Sure - do not specify them in your Makefile.

Answer (score -1):

You can create separate targets that are the same except for what you want to exclude.